Bot designer for Discord, ссылаться на сообщение от кнопки
Решил попрактиковаться с ботом в приложении "bot designer for Discord" но столкнулся с одной проблемой, я пытаюсь создать функцию при которой бот отправляет сообщение и даёт возможность его редактировать, после нажатия кнопки под сообщением даётся модальное окно.
Проблема в том что я заблудился и не понимаю как ссылаться на сообщение кнопка которого нажата, ну и исходя из этого достать channelID, messageID и содержимое сообщения которое я хочу редактировать после нажатия кнопки.
Вот код, 1часть,триггер: команда + текст
$nomention
$deleteMessage[$channelID;$messageID] (удаление сообщения пользователя после отправки команды) 
$message
$addButton[no;Change;Изменить;primary;no]
2часть, триггер: $onInteraction[Change]
$nomention
$newModal[Buffer;Изменить]
$addTextInput[Buffer;paragraph;Изменяемое сообщение:;1;4000;no;$getChannelVar[Message;$channelID]]

